# when equalizing images, skimage adds entropy and changes histogram when saving the images, how to preserve the equalized image?

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I've got the following image:

And I'm doing the following

- First I read an image `img = skimage.io.imread('original.jpg')` that has the following histogram:
  [image: histogram from the original image]
- Then, after applying `he_img = skimage.exposure.equalize_hist(a)`, I get the following histogram:
  [image: equalized original image]
- but when I save, then load and see the histogram of that image I get the following:
   `skimage.io.imsave(fname = 'he.jpg', arr= he_img)`
   `saved = skimage.io.imread('he.jpg')`
  [image: loaded image with HE]

What else do I need to add to my process in order to being able to save the equalized image?

Comment: That looks like a very nicely equalized histogram. What is the problem? The difference in histograms that you see is probably because the image is converted to an 8-bit unsigned integer for writing to file.

Comment: The problem is when saving the image, when loading it again I don't get the histogram displayed in the second histogram, probably the problem is the one you are mentioning. Any idea of how to not convert the image to an 8-bit? I would like to reproduce the same second histogram when loading the image

Comment: You need to save the image in floating-point format. You can do this with TIFF, but I don’t know which of the standard libraries support float TIFFs. You can also write it as a matrix, not to an image format. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Comment: Actually the problem was that jpg uses a lossy compression algorithm. It turns out that `TIFF` is a lossless compression format, but I used `PNG` since it is a more common format and it solved the problem. But thanks a lot, your answer guided me to find out what was the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this was that I was using `JPG`. `JPG` uses lossy compression to save images, adding noise to the image affecting to the equalization and increassing the images entropy.

To solve this I tried `PNG` that is a lossless compression format for storing images. The code for this is:

```
img = skimage.io.imread('original.jpg')
hist_equalized_img = skimage.exposure.equalize_hist(img)
skimage.io.imsave(fname = 'he.png', arr= hist_equalized_img)
```